# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto WinForms ClickOnce

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-forms

Hola Buenas Tardes ...

La situación es la siguiente ...

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en C# con WinForms, con bases de datos SQL, al momento de realizar las pruebas, funciona correctamente ... No se encuentra ningún problema ...

Estoy trabajando con el modelo de N Capas, para un mejor desarrollo de trabajo, además para la sencilla integración de módulos a futuro ...

Al momento de exportar con ClickOnce, realizo las pruebas con mi usuario y funciona correctamente ... En el trabajo, tengo mi usuario con los permisos establecidos a la base de datos y funciona perfectamente en otra PC, con mi usuario, pero, al momento de ingresar con otro usuario que tiene los mismos permisos en el servidor SQL y donde alojo la aplicación ... Al terminar la instalación (Sin ningún error), procedo a realizar las mismas operaciones que realizo con mi usuario, pero, la diferencia, es que me marca un error ...

[Adjunto Imagen]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se pregunta como se tienen las aplicaciones conectadas al servidor SQL, para corroborar que no sea un error de conexión y esta bien la conexión ...

Conexiones a SQL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SMTCProyects.CapaDatos
{
    public class Conexion_SqlServer
    {
        // Conexión a mxmca_apps
        public static string mxmca_appsCon = "Data Source=MCMX-SQL-DB-01;Initial Catalog=mxmca_apps;Integrated Security=SSPI";

        // Conexion a MXMCASQL
        public static string mxmcasql_Con = "Data Source=MXMCASQL;Initial Catalog = purchase; Integrated Security = SSPI";
    }
}
```

Clase D_Usuario

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SMTCProyects.CapaDatos
{
    public class D_Usuario
    {
        public int portalUserEmplopyeesNumber { get; set; }

        public D_Usuario() { }

        public D_Usuario(int number)
        {
            this.portalUserEmplopyeesNumber = number;
        }

        public DataTable Login(D_Usuario _Usuario)
        {
            DataTable dtUsuario = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection();

            try
            {
                SqlCon.ConnectionString = Conexion_SqlServer.mxmcasql_Con;

                SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;

                SqlCmd.CommandText = "spValidateUserBadge";
                SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@badgeUser", _Usuario.portalUserEmplopyeesNumber);

                SqlDataAdapter SqlDat = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd);
                SqlDat.Fill(dtUsuario);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                dtUsuario = null;
            }

            return dtUsuario;
        }
    }
}
```

Clase N_Usuario

```
using SMTCProyects.CapaDatos;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SMTCProyects.CapaNegocio
{
    public class N_Usuario
    {
        D_Usuario _Usuario = new D_Usuario();

        public DataTable Login(int badge)
        {
            _Usuario.portalUserEmplopyeesNumber = badge;
            return _Usuario.Login(_Usuario);
        }
    }
}
```

Formulario Principal

```
using SMTCProyects.CapaNegocio;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SMTCProyects.MessageBox;
using SMTCProyects.CapaPresentacion;

namespace SMTCProyects
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Objetos de Formularios de Success y Error
        Msg_Success _Success = new Msg_Success();
        Msg_Error _Error = new Msg_Error();

        // Para validar si pasa a PVS
        // 1 - Pasó Pruebas/Fusion
        // 0 - No pasó Pruebas/Fusion
        private int Test;

        N_DTVerificatorTest _DTVerificatorTest = new N_DTVerificatorTest();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            HabilitarCampos(false);
        }

        N_Usuario _Usuario = new N_Usuario();
        N_Pruebas _Pruebas = new N_Pruebas();
        N_spGetAssyMOByGTBarcode _SpGet = new N_spGetAssyMOByGTBarcode();
        N_TestRecords _TestRecords = new N_TestRecords();


        public void HabilitarCampos(bool habilitar)
        {
            txtEnsamble.Enabled = habilitar;
            txtNumSerial.Enabled = habilitar;
            txtRev.Enabled = habilitar;
        }

        public void DisableScanTargets(bool campUser)
        {
            txtEnsamble.Enabled = campUser;
            txtNumSerial.Enabled = campUser;
            txtRev.Enabled = campUser;
        }

        public void LimpiarCampos()
        {
            this.txtEnsamble.Text = "";
            this.txtNumSerial.Text = "";
            this.txtRev.Text = "";
            this.txtSerial.Text = "";
            this.txtEnsamble.Focus();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HabilitarCampos(false);
        }

        private void txtGafete_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((int)e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Enter)
            {
                DataTable dtUsuario = new DataTable();

                dtUsuario = _Usuario.Login(Convert.ToInt32(this.txtGafete.Text));

                if (dtUsuario.Rows.Count == 0 || dtUsuario == null)
                {
                    _Error.Title = "Error";
                    _Error.Title = "No existe el usuario";
                    _Error.ShowDialog();
                    this.txtGafete.Text = "";
                    this.txtGafete.Focus();
                    HabilitarCampos(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.btnNom.Text = dtUsuario.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    this.btnNumber.Text = dtUsuario.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    HabilitarCampos(true);
                    this.txtGafete.Text = "";
                    txtGafete.Enabled = false;
                    txtEnsamble.Focus();
                }
            }
        }

        private void txtRev_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((int)e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Enter)
            {
                this.txtSerial.Text = this.txtEnsamble.Text + this.txtNumSerial.Text + this.txtRev.Text;
                DataTable dtPruebas = new DataTable();
                dtPruebas = _Pruebas.VerifyTestDT(this.txtNumSerial.Text);
                if (dtPruebas.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    Test = 1;
                    if (Test == 1)
                    {
                        DataTable dtFusion = _SpGet.InfoFusion(txtSerial.Text);

                        if (dtFusion.Rows.Count > 0 && dtFusion != null)
                        {
                            string rptaTest = _TestRecords.Insertar("FT", txtSerial.Text, dtFusion.Rows[0][0].ToString(), Convert.ToBoolean(1), DateTime.Now.ToString(), btnNumber.Text);
                            string rpta = _DTVerificatorTest.Insertar(dtFusion.Rows[0][2].ToString(), dtFusion.Rows[0][0].ToString(), txtNumSerial.Text, txtRev.Text, txtSerial.Text, 1, btnNumber.Text, btnNom.Text);

                            _Success.Title = "Acción concretada";
                            _Success.Message = "La unidad pasa a PVS.";
                            _Success.ShowDialog();
                        }
                        else if (dtFusion.Rows.Count == 0 && dtFusion == null)
                        {
                            string rptaTest = _TestRecords.Insertar("FT", txtSerial.Text, txtEnsamble.Text, Convert.ToBoolean(0), DateTime.Now.ToString(), btnNumber.Text);
                            string rpta = _DTVerificatorTest.Insertar("", "", txtNumSerial.Text, txtRev.Text, txtSerial.Text, 0, btnNumber.Text, btnNom.Text);

                            _Error.Title = "Error";
                            _Error.Title = "No contiene registros de Fusion FQA";
                            _Error.ShowDialog();
                        }

                        LimpiarCampos();
                    }
                }
                else if (dtPruebas.Rows.Count == 0 && dtPruebas == null)
                {
                    _Error.Title = "Error";
                    _Error.Title = "No contiene registros de Pruebas";
                    _Error.ShowDialog();
                    string rpta = _DTVerificatorTest.Insertar("", "", txtNumSerial.Text, txtRev.Text, txtSerial.Text, 0, btnNumber.Text, btnNom.Text);
                    this.LimpiarCampos();
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnClose_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void txtEnsamble_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if((int)e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Tab)
            {
                this.txtNumSerial.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void txtNumSerial_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((int)e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Tab)
            {
                this.txtRev.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frm_Reports _Reports = new Frm_Reports();
            this.Hide();
            _Reports.Show();
        }

        private void sfButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LimpiarCampos();
            HabilitarCampos(false);
            txtGafete.Enabled = true;
            LimpiarCampos();
            btnNom.Text = "";
            btnNumber.Text = "";
            txtGafete.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Eh buscado varias maneras, pero, no eh encontrado la información necesaria, a lo que eh encontrado, todo esta en orden, pero, no se que es lo que está sucediendo ...

Comment: Agrega un logger para guardar los errores y usa try catch digamos en tu ultimo nivel asi sabras  cual es la excepcion de otro modo solo estaras adivinando.

Comment: Cada vez que leo programación N capas y veo el code behind de un form o user control me dan ganas de reír xD.